# Adding highscores to java game - From console to JPanel - Saving highscore in encrypted text file

Tags: java, swing, encryption, read-write

I am new to Java, and learning new things everyday. English is not my mother language, I'm sorry.
So, I'm making a maze game in Java to learn while writing code.
For my maze game, the player needs to get to the exit of the maze asap. And the time he has, needs to be saved in an encrypted text file. 
So I've got a package Highscores combining several classes. The code works more or less, it outputs in the console. Now what I need is that that output gets outputted on a JPanel next to my maze. I've added some extra info in the code
Here is my highscore class:

```
    public class Highscore {
// An arraylist of the type "score" we will use to work with the scores inside the class
private ArrayList<Score> scores;

// The name of the file where the highscores will be saved
private static final String highscorefile = "Resources/scores.dat";

//Initialising an in and outputStream for working with the file
ObjectOutputStream output = null;
ObjectInputStream input = null;

public Highscore() {
    //initialising the scores-arraylist
    scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
}
public ArrayList<Score> getScores() {
    loadScoreFile();
    sort();
    return scores;
}
private void sort() {
    ScoreVergelijken comparator = new ScoreVergelijken();
    Collections.sort(scores, comparator);
}
public void addScore(String name, int score) {
    loadScoreFile();
    scores.add(new Score(name, score));
    updateScoreFile();
}
public void loadScoreFile() {
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(highscorefile));
        scores = (ArrayList<Score>) input.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("[Laad] FNF Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[Laad] IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("[Laad] CNF Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[Laad] IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public void updateScoreFile() {
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(highscorefile));
        output.writeObject(scores);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("[Update] FNF Error: " + e.getMessage() + ",the program will try and make a new file");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("[Update] IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.flush();
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[Update] Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public String getHighscoreString() {
    String highscoreString = "";
       int max = 10;

    ArrayList<Score> scores;
    scores = getScores();

    int i = 0;
    int x = scores.size();
    if (x > max) {
        x = max;
    }
    while (i < x) {
        highscoreString += (i + 1) + ".\t" + scores.get(i).getNaam() + "\t\t" + scores.get(i).getScore() + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    return highscoreString;
}
```

}

Here is my Main class:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Highscore hm = new Highscore();
    hm.addScore("Bart",240);
    hm.addScore("Marge",300);
    hm.addScore("Maggie",220);
    hm.addScore("Homer",100);
    hm.addScore("Lisa",270);
    hm.addScore(LabyrinthProject.View.MainMenu.username,290);

    System.out.print(hm.getHighscoreString());
} }
```

Score class :

```
public class Score  implements Serializable {
private int score;
private String naam;

public Score() {

}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public String getNaam() {
    return naam;
}

public Score(String naam, int score) {
    this.score = score;
    this.naam = naam;
}
```

}

ScoreVergelijken class (which means CompareScore)

```
public class ScoreVergelijken implements Comparator<Score> {
public int compare(Score score1, Score score2) {

    int sc1 = score1.getScore();
    int sc2 = score2.getScore();

    if (sc1 > sc2){
        return -1;                   // -1 means first score is bigger then second score
    }else if (sc1 < sc2){
        return +1;                   // +1 means that score is lower
    }else{
        return 0;                     // 0 means score is equal
    }
}  }
```

If anyone could explain to me what to use, it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Also, how to use those highscores and store them encrypted in a text file. How can I achieve that?

Sincerely, A beginner java student.

Answer (score 0):

to keep your data encrypted in a file, you can use CipherIn/OutputStream, just like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // got this example from http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/UsingCipherInputStream.htm
    write();
    read();
}

public static void write() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    kg.init(new SecureRandom());
    SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    Class spec = Class.forName("javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec");
    DESKeySpec ks = (DESKeySpec) skf.getKeySpec(key, spec);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("keyfile"));
    oos.writeObject(ks.getKey());

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CFB8/NoPadding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ciphertext"), c);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cos));
    pw.println("Stand and unfold yourself");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    oos.writeObject(c.getIV());
    oos.close();
}

public static void read() throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("keyfile"));
    DESKeySpec ks = new DESKeySpec((byte[]) ois.readObject());
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(ks);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CFB8/NoPadding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec((byte[]) ois.readObject()));
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream("ciphertext"), c);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cis));
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still need help on the other problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you asked two questions and Leo [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339123/adding-highscores-to-java-game-from-console-to-jpanel-saving-highscore-in-en/22339860#22339860) your second question.

Your first question is...

> what I need is that ...[the high scores]... gets outputted on a `JPanel` next to my maze

You didn't post any GUI code, but a subclass of [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html) would be more appropriate than a `JPanel`. Simply add a component, for example `JTextArea` and call its `setText()` method with your *high score string* as the method argument.